# How to upsert with mongodb-java-driver

Tags: java, mongodb, upsert

How can I upsert data into mongodb collection with java-driver?

I try (with empty collection):

```
db.getCollection(collection).update(new BasicDBObject("_id", "12"), dbobject, true, false);
```

But document was created with _id == ObjectID(...). Not with "12" value.

This code (js) add document with _id = "12" as expected

```
db.metaclass.update(
   { _id:12},
   {
     $set: {b:1}
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

mongo-java-driver-2.11.2

Comment: Using Jongo: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41103427/435605

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot set `_id` if `dbobject` is just a document and does not contain an update operator eg: `$set`, `$setOnInsert`.

Just passing a document will replace the **whole document** meaning it doesn't set an `_id` a falls back to `ObjectId`

So your example works if you use an update operator eg:

```
db.getCollection(collection).update(
    new BasicDBObject("_id", "12"), 
    new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("Hi", "world")), true, false)
```

Answer (score 27):

If you are using [mongo-java driver 3](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/), following `.updateOne()` method with `{upsert, true}` flag works.

```
 void setLastIndex(MongoClient mongo, Long id, Long lastIndexValue) {

    Bson filter = Filters.eq("_id", id);

    Bson update =  new Document("$set",
                  new Document()
                        .append("lastIndex", lastIndexValue)
                        .append("created", new Date()));
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

    mongo.getDatabase(EventStreamApp.EVENTS_DB)
         .getCollection(EventCursor.name)
         .updateOne(filter, update, options);
  }
```

Comment: Any example of how will you use $set and $setOnInsert in the same update query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `replaceOne` method and specify the `ReplaceOptions` (since 3.7) :

```
private static final ReplaceOptions REPLACE_OPTIONS
      = ReplaceOptions.createReplaceOptions(new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));  

db.getCollection(collection).replaceOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", "12"), dbobject, REPLACE_OPTIONS);
```

For older versions you can directly pass the `UpdateOptions` to the replaceOne method :

```
private static final UpdateOptions UPDATE_POLICY = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
db.getCollection(collection).replaceOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", "12"), dbobject, UPDATE_POLICY);
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/#behavior) :

> replaceOne() replaces the first matching document in the collection
>   that matches the filter, using the replacement document.
>
> If upsert: true and no documents match the filter, replaceOne()
>   creates a new document based on the replacement document.

Answer (score -1):

This is to upsert with scala driver which i couldnot find in web

```
con.updateOne(  
            equal("vendor_id", vendorId),          
            inc("views_count", f.views),
            UpdateOptions().upsert(true))
```

to do so import the following

```
import org.mongodb.scala.model.UpdateOptions
```